# Read the file from one Unix server to the other Unix server

Tags: files, ksh, scp

I have a `Pro*C` program which I run on Unix server `a` but the input file required for this program is on other Unix server `b`. Whenever I run I have to copy the file from server `b` to `a`.

Is there any way that I can access the file from other server while running the program to give file name as the whole path which is on server `b`

Answer (score 2):

If your OS supports FUSE, you can use [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to mount a remote directory to a local one.

Otherwise, assuming your shell is `bash`, you can still do it like this:

```
program <(ssh b 'cat /path/to/file')
```

But this only works if your program only wants to read from the file on machine b.

Comment: i am using `ksh`, will it work in the ksh

Comment: No, ksh doesn't support `<(...)` constructs (at least as far as I remember).

Comment: I think ksh invented `<(…)` (like most post-Bourne shell programming constructs). It dates back from before ksh93, but it wasn't added to pdksh. @Aravind

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is **Bash**, you can do it like this:

```
ssh user@hostname.com "cat -f /path/to/file"
```

Comment: or if the program can read from STDIN run ssh to get the file and pipe it to the program